# Top extra layer tree entry is blank in my QGIS Server WMS drop down menu

Tags: qgis, wms, qgis-server, apache

I have set up a QGIS server using apache on Windows and have added some test data, but compared to other WMS layers added from other organisations, there appears to be an extra layer to my layers tree before getting to the data which has been added and named by myself.

[image]

As seen in the image above there is another, nameless branch in the layer tree of my 'ALIAS TEST' WMS layer compared to the 'NI Geology' one above it.

Is there a way to remove this extra branch of the layer tree in my WMS layer using QGIS Server, or is it something I have to live with?

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you're using a QGIS Server version < 3.18.

The root layer name is blank because there's no project title set (in the *General* tab, not the *QGIS Server* tab of *Project Properties*).

So you could name the root layer by setting a project title (Project → Properties → General → Project title).

**Please note:**

For QGIS Server version >= 3.18 the logic is defferent, from https://github.com/qgis/QGIS/pull/40758 :

If Project → Properties → QGIS Server → Service Capabilities → Title is available, it is used for root layer Title.

If it's not available, we use the project's title Project → Properties → General → Project title.

Only if project's title is also not set, we use *untitled*.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your response. My instance is running QGIS 3.16.15 and I have tried adding a title to both the locations you have mentioned but for some reason after doing so if refuses to connect and says 'unable to get capabilities' It does begin to work again of these titles are left blank again and resaved